# img-circle, figure caption as circle also

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to add player profiles to a website I'm creating. I wish to have the player in a cirlce image and their number in a circle at the bottom right of the image.Like so (sorry for quality)

[What I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5MjV.png)

Here is my fiddle so far:

```
<figure class="profile">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140" class="img-circle" />
  <figcaption>12</figcaption>
</figure>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/78wzcydL/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/78wzcydL/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.profile {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<figure class="profile">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
  <figcaption class="img-circle">12</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to absolute position the caption:

```
figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}


figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

[Check the sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/78wzcydL/4/)